# Many binary columns: need to reduce to fewer binary columns using grouping information in a second dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes. I am trying to use information in one to reduce the number of binary columns in the other. df1 is some sample data, where var is the presence or absence of a gene variant and ID = individuals.

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 
                  var1 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0),
                  var2 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
                  var3 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1),
                  var4 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0))
```

df2 is the updated classification of the gene variants into more general classes. Here, var1 and var2 are classified together (gen = 1) and var3 and var4 are together (gen = 2).

```
df2<-data.frame(ID = c('var1','var2','var3','var4'),
                gen = c(1,1,2,2))
```

I want my final data table to show the presence or absence of these more general classes of gene variants, like this:

```
df3<-data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 
                var1 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0),
                var2 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
                var3 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1),
                var4 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
                gen1 = c(1,1,0,0,1,0),
                gen2 = c(0,0,1,1,0,1))
```

```
> df3
  ID var1 var2 var3 var4 gen1 gen2
1  1    1    1    0    0    1    0
2  2    1    0    0    0    1    0
3  3    0    0    0    1    0    1
4  4    0    0    1    0    0    1
5  5    1    1    0    0    1    0
6  6    0    0    1    0    0    1
```

I know there must be a way to solve this problem and I just cannot figure it out.
Any suggestions would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID) %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c('name' = 'ID')) %>%
  group_by(ID, gen) %>%
  summarise(value = +(any(value ==1)), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  mutate(gen = str_c('gen', gen)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = gen, values_from = value) %>% 
  left_join(df1, . ) %>%
  select(names(df1), everything())
```

-output

```
#   ID var1 var2 var3 var4 gen1 gen2
#1  1    1    1    0    0    1    0
#2  2    1    0    0    0    1    0
#3  3    0    0    0    1    0    1
#4  4    0    0    1    0    0    1
#5  5    1    1    0    0    1    0
#6  6    0    0    1    0    0    1
```

---

Or use `rowSums`

```
df1 %>% 
 mutate(gen1 = +(rowSums(select(., df2$ID[df2$gen == 1]) > 0) > 0), 
       gen2 = +(rowSums(select(., df2$ID[df2$gen == 2]) > 0) > 0) )
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun so much for your speedy help. Your solutions worked and you have saved me from frustration! I upvoted your answer but I am new and it won't let me.

Comment: Of these possible solutions, I ended up using the rowSums option. This was because it was easy for me to apply it to my more-complicated real dataset (and it worked).

Answer (score 0):

in base R you would do:

```
cbind(df1, gen = do.call(cbind, by(df2$ID, df2$gen, function(x)+Reduce("|", df1[x]))))
  ID var1 var2 var3 var4 gen.1 gen.2
1  1    1    1    0    0     1     0
2  2    1    0    0    0     1     0
3  3    0    0    0    1     0     1
4  4    0    0    1    0     0     1
5  5    1    1    0    0     1     0
6  6    0    0    1    0     0     1
```

You could also do:

```
cbind(df1, gen = +sapply(split.default(df1[-1], df2$gen), Reduce, f = "|"))

  ID var1 var2 var3 var4 gen.1 gen.2
1  1    1    1    0    0     1     0
2  2    1    0    0    0     1     0
3  3    0    0    0    1     0     1
4  4    0    0    1    0     0     1
5  5    1    1    0    0     1     0
6  6    0    0    1    0     0     1
```

Comment: Thank you @Onyambu so much for your speedy help. Your solutions worked and you have saved me from frustration! I upvoted your answer but I am new and it won't let me.